# How do I override Storyboard UIView height property programatically

Tags: ios, constraints, overriding, height, uistoryboard

I have placed a small `UIView` in my `viewController` and set its `constraints` left, right and bottom. In order not to get a `constraint error` I have to add a height as well. I don't want to keep this height though, as I would like it to be dynamically set in its `viewController` like this:

```
bottomBar.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.height / 10
```

I thought this would `override` the `constraint` value I set in the `storyBoard` but it doesn't work. I have set it to `/ 2` just to see what happens, but it still keeps the `storyboard` value. How do I `override` this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an IBOutlet connection from that constraint you added in your storyboard to the ViewController. 
ForExample in below image:
[image: Showing how to add IBOutlet for constraint]

Once you have a connection you could do like:

```
self.newlyAddedConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.height / 10;
```

Thats all. your height will be adjusted. Depending on where you are setting this constant you might also need to call

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded]
```

Comment: Alright, nice, it worked perfectly! Thanks for taking the time helping me out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can link you storyboard height constraint to an outlet:

```swift
@IBOutlet var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

then later you can change it:

```swift
heightConstraint.constant = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove storyboard constraint at build time. Just choose needed constraint and select "Remove at build time".